# I can't get JsBarcode to work correctly

Tags: javascript

I am having some trouble getting JsBarcode to work correctly. I'm pretty new to Javascript and unsure really how to set this up correctly. Below you can view my code, any suggestions would help a ton! The I would ideally want to get the CODE39 setup, but I tried pulling the example they had on the site just to see if It would work but no luck.

```js
JsBarcode("#barcode", "Red lines", {
  lineColor: "#990000"
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jsbarcode/3.3.7/barcodes/JsBarcode.ean-upc.min.js"></script>

<svg class="barcode"
  jsbarcode-format="upc"
  jsbarcode-value="123456789012"
  jsbarcode-textmargin="0"
  jsbarcode-fontoptions="bold">
</svg>
```

Thanks guys!!

Answer (score 1):

you should just change class keeyword to id, and everything would work